# Migrating project from angular 5 to 8 problems with Response -> HttpResponse

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

apparently you need to do the Http changes by hand before migrating
as `@angular/http` disappears in favor of `@angular/common/http` and all the classes change a bit.

```
public getData<T>(pathMock: string, pathApi: string): Observable<T> {
    let base: string = (this.getMockIdx()) ? `${AppGlobal.BASE_URL}` : `${AppGlobal.API_URL}`;
    let path: string = (this.getMockIdx()) ? `${pathMock}` : pathApi;
    let url: string = `${base}${path}`;
    return this.http.get(
        url
    ).map((response:  HttpResponse<any>) => {
        let result: T = response;
        return result;
    });
}
```

this is what I have I changed `Response` to `HttpResponse<any>` (I put any because I just want it to work and I don't know what to put).

this triggers the following error message :

[image: is not assignable to the constraint of type 'T']

"...is not assignable to the constraint of type 'T'"

but if I change T it goes even more haywire :

[image]

Update After Answer:

```
return this.http.get<any>(`${AppGlobal.API_URL}my/api/auth/refresh/tokens`,
  this.getRequestOptions()).pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
      return this.decryptToken(data);
    }
  ));
```

[image: with second passed argument there is also a error]

with second passed argument there is also an error :
"Argument of type header: header is not assignable to ...

what is going on here?

Comment: Please don't edit the question *just* because an answer didn't work. You can comment on the corresponding answer itself.

Comment: your answer worked (I used yours first and it worked with the map import, then AJT answered and his explanation and verbose was objectively better ) the reason I'm expanding my question is I'm realizing there was more depth to it, some more detailed cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you get with `HttpClient` **isn't** `HttpResponse`, but `HttpClient` already parses your response, so what you get is an **anonymous object**. I see that you are using `any`. Avoid that at all cost, type your data, makes your life easier. But here, I will use `any`, since you have not typed your data. Also like in other answer, update rxjs if you already haven't to use pipeable operators. Also I don't see any use for actually using `map` since you are not doing anything with the data inside `map`, but if you do, it should look like:

```ts
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

// replace 'any' with your type, for example an interface
return this.http.get<any>('url').pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    return data;
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks. I've marked you a answer but I've found a slightly different syntax where I pass what I imagine i the body's parameter and it give's me an error there. what is the correct syntax in that case? (I've updated my question with this code segment)

Comment: @tatsu, you have a typing issue there also. `Http` used `Headers`, whereas `HttpClient` uses `HttpHeaders`, so `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'` and replace `Headers` with `HttpHeaders`. Remember that `HttpHeaders` are immutable in contrary to `Headers`, so make sure you are setting them [correctly](https://angular.io/guide/http#updating-headers) :)

Comment: thanks, uhm it's in the same file and headers is not imported at all (but tslint, JS interpreter seems to be fine with that fact)...

Comment: I suggest you read the `HttpClient` documentation as a whole, since you are updating from `Http` to `HttpClient`, so there might be some other issues you run into. But anyway, so did you solve the header issue? :)

Comment: no this header is still considered to be incorrect by my IDE

Comment: Could you post the function `getRequestOptions()` code please.

Comment: my bad. you were right, it returned a `Headers` instead of a `HttpHeaders` all good now. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `pipe()` to chain other RxJS operators, in this case `map()`

```
return this.http.get('url').
   pipe(
      map((response:  HttpResponse<any>) => {
         return response;
      })
   );
```

Comment: Did you import the `map()`? Use `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`